# ¿Cómo obtener altura 100% en tag embed?

Tags: html5, pdf

Quiero colocar un PDF embebido a través del tag `<embed src="">` sin embargo al definir la altura(`height`) del mismo no funciona, tengo lo siguiente:

```
<embed src="test.pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
```

El ancho(`width`) funciona correctamente, pero la altura no se muestra al 100%.

**¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?**

Answer (score 0):

Debes establecer la altura del *body* y *html* para que *embed* pueda tomar el 100%

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

o en lugar de usar porcentaje usar las unidades vh

```
embed{
  height:100vh;
}
```